# Can Google chart api controlwrapper for a line chart interpolate nulls?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a google line chart controlled by a controlwrapper working fine, but the line chart options have interpolateNulls set to true, but I cannot get the controlwrapper to function the same way, making the controlwrapper's lines appear fragmented. How do I make a line chart controlwrapper interpolateNulls?

Comment: Assuming this is a ChartRangeFilter, you need to set the `ui.chartOptions.interpolateNulls` option to `true`.

Comment: Thank you. I was setting ui.interpolateNulls to true. Now it works.